# How to define Lens into the State value itself?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, state-monad

While trying to understand State monad and use of Lens with it, I arrived at a surprisingly trivial definition of a lens for a simple counter:

```
self :: ASetter s s s s
self = ($)

incrementUsingLens :: State Int ()
incrementUsingLens = self %= (+1)
```

Since

```
type ASetter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t
```

In my case is just

```
type ASetter s s s s = (s -> Identity s) -> s -> Identity s
```

Is this is indeed a correct definition for a lens into a state variable? I'm worried that I might be missing some laws or other assumptions.

Comment: `self` can actually be given a much more general type. It's not just an `ASetter`; it's an `Equality`. Its most general lensy type is `Equality a b a b`, but you may want to use the `Equality' a a` version, which is `Control.Lens.Equality.simple`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lens* calls this do-nothing optic [`simple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Equality.html#v:simple). Note that `simple` is an `Equality`, and `Equality` is at the very bottom of the optics hierarchy, which means you can use it not only as a do-nothing setter, but also as a do-nothing lens, prism, etc.

> I'm worried that I might be missing some laws or other assumptions.

The setter laws say that, for a `foo` setter, `over foo` should follow the functor laws:

```
over foo id = id
over foo (g . f) = over foo g . over foo f
```

If you try this with `simple`/`id`, you will find the laws hold trivially. The same goes for the other optic laws.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `($)`, also called `id`, is also a lens in the representation of the lens package. Though here we have `get`, `put`, `modify` that work just as well, the identity lens can still be useful sometimes.